# Select elements with certain class and not other classes

Tags: javascript, css

Using javascript, I am looking to select `div` elements that are members of a class while not being members of anther class. In the following example, I would like to choose `div` elements that are a part of class `b` while not in class `a`. This should result in only 4 being selected, as 3 is a part of class `a`.

```
<body>
  <div>1<div>
  <div class="a">2</div>
  <div class="a b">3</div>
  <div class="b">4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: $(".b:not(.a)")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select them with a query Selector and `:not`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div.b:not(.a)"))
```

```html
    <div class="a">2</div>
    <div class="a b">3</div>
    <div class="b">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.b:not(.a)');
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<div>1<div>
<div class="a">2</div>
<div class="a b">3</div>
<div class="b">4</div>
```

result is `div.b` which contains the number 4, (a node list) this works for all elements not just divs. If you only want to work within divs just change the selector to `div.b:not(.a)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: This works, but just needed to select only `div` as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
var has_a = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("a"));
var has_b = has_a.filter(e=>!e.classList.contains('b'));

// replace the arrow notation with a lambda if you can't use it
```

`has_b` is now an array containing elements with class `a`, but not class `b`.

If you can't use `Array.from`, replace with a loop:

```
var has_a = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
var has_b = [];
for (var i=0; i<has_a.length; ++i) {
    if (!has_a[i].classList.contains('b'))
        has_b.push(has[i]);
```